# Removing tool bar oddly slow

Tags: init-file, start-up, tool-bar

`(tool-bar-mode 0)` takes up 11% of my initialization time (about a third of  a second). It's not that big of a deal; it's just *strange*. I've tried it on multiple computers. I've also tried disabling everything but that line in my `.emacs`. It always takes a while.

Is this normal? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How do you *know* it's this line?  What version of Emacs is this?  I'd like to see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: I first noticed it when I was profiling my `.emacs`. I ran that line by itself by commenting everything out, with the same result. I have tried `24.4 stable` and `25.0 snapshot`, on Windows and Ubuntu respectively.

Comment: After adding the line to my init.el, the initialization time still comes out to be the same. Are you checking the time with M-x emacs-init-time?

Comment: Yep. With an empty init file, `emacs-init-time` takes 0.5 seconds. With `(tool-bar-mode 0)`, it takes 0.8 seconds.

Comment: To be clear, I'm aware that 0.3 seconds is pretty trivial. I just find it strangely out of place with the relative speed of comparable Emacs customizations.

Comment: Set `Emacs.toolBar: 0` in *~/.Xresources* file. Any modification related to X window will be faster that way, because it will be applied *before* window is created|mapped.

Comment: No change. I don't have an existing `~/.Xresources` file, so I created one. Do I have to do something specific so that Emacs loads it? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I've also tried `emacs24.toolBar: 0`

Comment: Hello. Try: `Emacs*toolBar: false`

Comment: I think you need to `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresouces` before starting Emacs.

Comment: You could always use my technique...my init file is now so complicated that an extra .3 secs is negligible. :-)  I just don't start emacs that often.  When I was working on a daily basis, it was started as part of the login, while I was off getting the day's first can of Mt. Dew.  By the time I got back, everything was running...now that I'm a consultant working from home I only start an emacs when there's a power failure (current emacs has been running for about 2 months from an early May storm outage) still started from login.

Comment: I've no idea whether it makes a difference, but which X toolkit are you using? Have you tried compiling emacs with a different one?

Answer (score 5):

A slightly less general but simpler version of what `tool-bar-mode` does:

```el
(push '(tool-bar-lines . 0) default-frame-alist)
```

The same can be done with `menu-bar-mode` and the `menu-bar-lines` frame parameter, if you are interested.

Note that this will likely only shave a few cycles, if any. :)