# tool-bar in emacsclient

Tags: init-file, emacsclient, emacs-daemon, tool-bar

I have the following for ridding of the toolbar on startup in graphical mode in my init configuration:

```
(if window-system
    (tool-bar-mode -1)
)
```

**the issue:**

it works fine (albeit slow...[see this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32661/17548)) when starting emacs but does not work with the `emacs --daemon` , starting `emacsclient c` starts a graphical client with toolbar ( I want without). Does emacs graphical client require a seperate code to the `if window-system`?

**I run:**

emacs 25.3 on Linux manjaro 17.1.5 Hakolla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution to your actual problem -- avoiding the tool bar -- is to customize `tool-bar-mode` to `nil`.
Alternatively you can also put `(setq tool-bar-mode nil)` into your init file.

The problem with `window-system` in emacs daemon is that the virtual frame of the emacs daemon is not connected to any display. Since the init file runs in the daemon `window-system` is nil.

Furthermore, you shouldn't use `windows-system` as bool variable. Use `display-graphic-p` instead. See the last section of [the windows-systems doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html).

The server creates display frames for clients on demand (with option `--create-frame`).

Therefore, `after-make-frame-functions` is the right place to hook in if you want to tweak your graphical frames generated by an emacs daemon. In the following I give you an example:

```el
(defun my-frame-tweaks (&optional frame)
  "My personal frame tweaks."
  (unless frame
    (setq frame (selected-frame)))
  (when frame
    (with-selected-frame frame
      (when (display-graphic-p)
    (tool-bar-mode -1)))))

;; For the case that the init file runs after the frame has been created.
;; Call of emacs without --daemon option.
(my-frame-tweaks) 
;; For the case that the init file runs before the frame is created.
;; Call of emacs with --daemon option.
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'my-frame-tweaks t)
```

Comment: and thanks for the explenation. I will read the windows-systems doc now.  @Tobias

Comment: @manandearth Have you tried just to customize the variable `tool-bar-mode` to nil? That should work for global modes like `tool-bar-mode`. (I never tried in connection with the emacs daemon.) That would be the simplest solution and if you checked it positively I would add it in front of my answer.

Comment: It's also possible to just make a check with `featurep`.

Comment: @Tobias It doesn't work with `tool-bar-mode` set to nil. not for the `emacsclient`

Comment: @manandearth I've just tried it and it works for me. So I added it in front of my answer.

Comment: @Tobias Yes it does work with `(setq tool-bar-mode nil)` , I was trying to set it to nil in my original    `(if window-system
    (tool-bar-mode -1)
)`      which doesn't work, of course for the reasons you mention regarding the `window-sytem` in your answer